# SELECT DISTINCT return incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to solve a code challenge:


Provide a list (site id, site name) of distinct active sites who have one or more domain,
and whose domains are ​all​ deleted.

The query I did is:

```
select 
s.id as 'site id',
s.name as 'site name'
from sites s
inner join companies c on c.id = s.company
where c.is_on_hold != 1
and c.is_deleted != 1
and s.is_deleted != 1
and s.id in (select site from domains where is_deleted = 1)
```

Which gives me 9 results, 
I've been told that it shloud output just 6,
Can anyone explain why?

[DB Fiddle Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4nsMLMH1udKSzpnEgfqpRq/1)

Comment: Very hard to help without some sample data and expected result. The title says distinct but you are not using distinct which is confusing

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I haven't used distinct because the results shows that there are only 9 unique results anyway

Comment: Are you sure you was told that there are 6 *sites*? I have a guess that you should have 6 *companies*. Check it with stakeholder. If that is the case - I have my query filter for you, but it is definitely not a good SO question. PS: no I have 5 as result

Comment: @Alex I just told that the results should be 6 sites, I'm getting 9 sites and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of your requirement is:

> ...and whose domains are **​all**​ deleted

so i guess the last condition instead of:

```
and s.id in (select site from domains where is_deleted = 1)
```

should be:

```
and s.id in (
  select site 
  from domains 
  group by site
  having min(is_deleted) = 1
)
```

this subquery returns all the sites for which the minimum `is_deleted` is `1` meaning that there is no `is_deleted = 0`, so all sites are deleted.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4nsMLMH1udKSzpnEgfqpRq/6).
Results:

```
| site id | site name  |
| ------- | ---------- |
| 31      | Wisconsin  |
| 53      | Washington |
| 62      | Wyoming    |
| 83      | Nevada     |
| 87      | Florida    |
| 96      | Indiana    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are getting all sites with at least one deleted domain, while you want all domaims deleted.

Change the last part of your query to:

```
and s.id not in (select site from domains where is_deleted = 0)
```

Comment: That gives me 18 results, the results should be just 6 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and added a subquery at the end. I have a total of 6 rows.

My approach is as follows:
assuming `is_deleted` is integer type or compatible, then it can be SUMmed up. Thus, if you group the domains by **site**, and `sum(is_deleted)` is equal to the number (count) of records per site, then it means all the domains for that site are **deleted**.
If you run the subselect as a stand-alone query that should become clear. Hopefully this is the result you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
s.id as 'site id',
s.name as 'site name'
FROM sites s
INNER join companies c ON c.id = s.company
WHERE c.is_on_hold != 1
AND c.is_deleted != 1
AND s.is_deleted != 1
AND s.id IN (
    SELECT site /*, sum(is_deleted), count(*) */
    FROM domains
    GROUP BY site
    HAVING SUM(is_deleted) = COUNT(*)
    ORDER BY site
)
```